# Conditional Expression for variable is not working in ZSHVER=5.9

Tags: conditional-operator

Any idea why -v is not working in version 5.9?

```
% unset foo;

% [[ -v foo ]] && echo "foo";
zsh: unknown condition: -v
```

Directly from section "12 Conditional Expressions" in the docs...

-v varname
true if shell variable varname is set.

UPDATE:  I have whittled it down to something in my environment.  If I start a new shell, it works as expected.  No differences with setopt settings or zsh version.  I resourced my dot files in the new shell with no luck.

If it start a new shell, then from that shell start an new xterm, then I have the same problem in the new xterm, so this feels like a problem with how the shell is starting in new xterms.

Answer (score 0):

Bind key for opening an new xterm was pointing the shell to an older version; everything else on the system is pointing to 5.9.  I should have started with $ZSH_VERSION from the beginning...

```
% echo $ZSH_VERSION
5.0.2
```

Feature I was using was not part of ZSH until version 5.3.